# Rails scope for values only between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope

I like to have a scope in Rails for selecting only values between two dates.

Here is my example:

I have a model with the attribute '*startDate*' and '*endDate*'. Both have the type '*date*'

Now I want to select every entry from today, which is between these two dates.

I made a scope looks like this.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :activeDate, -> { where("? >= ? AND ? <= ?", Time.now.to_date, :saleStartDate, Time.now.to_date, :salesEndDate)}
```

In the controller:

```
@products = Product.activeDate
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Is there a rails-way (more beautiful) to get all entries?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ruby convention would have your scope called active_date instead of activeDate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do this:

```
scope :activeDate, -> { where("? BETWEEN startDate AND endDate", Time.now.to_date)}
```

Since you are using greater *or equal* AND lesser *or equal*, you can use the equivalent SQL function "BETWEEN".

You don't need to convert the Time to a date,you can directly call the Date.today:

```
scope :activeDate, -> { where("? BETWEEN startDate AND endDate", Date.today)}
```

---

You could **improve your scope** by doing this:

```
scope :activeAtDate, lambda{ |date = Date.today| where("? BETWEEN startDate AND endDate", date) }
```

And use it like this:

```
Product.activeAtDate() #=> use the Date.today
Product.activeAtDate(1.week.ago.to_date) #=> use Today - minus 7 days
```

Comment: I will also note that when you use a scope like this, if you end up chaining or eager loading models with the same columns like `startDate` or `endDate` you may get a ambiguous column reference error. I fixed that with `where("? BETWEEN #{table_name}.startDate AND #{table_name}.endDate"` in my case.