# Rails scope between two dates in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to define a scope to use it in initializer which will represents something like

```
class GenerateCsv 
   def itnialize(start_date:, end_date:)
     ,,,
   end 

   def call 
     AdminLog.dates_between(start_date, end_date).each do |record| 
       Csv.generate ...
     end
   end
 end
```

How to define this `dates_between` scope to use it in a call method?

in my `AdminLog model` I've got `created_at` field which should be used to define this range

`model`:

```
# created_at  :datetime         not null

class AdminPanelLog < ApplicationRecord
  scope :dates_between { |start_date, end_date| }
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails scope for values only between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18661777/rails-scope-for-values-only-between-two-dates)

Comment: @KevinBrown In my case `start_date` and `end_date` are not a field in model, those are just variable which user will defined, so this is a little bit different case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you but maybe this is what you want?

```
scope :dates_between, lambda { |start_date, end_date|
  where('created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', start_date, end_date)
}
```

EDIT: note that you could use `where(created_at: start_date..end_date)` to create a "between" query (`WHERE created_at BETWEEN ... AND ...`) instead

Comment: Thanks for your response, but should I use this `|start_date, end_date|` ? rubocop showed me syntax error.

Comment: it depends, what's the error? note that rubocop expects `lambda { |something| ...` or `->(something) { ...` syntaxes